# Реализация кнопки "Поделится"

Tags: android

В галереи и в других программах есть кнопка Поделиться, которая открывает окно с программами, в которые можно отправить выбранный файл. Интересно, как это реализовать? У меня .mp3 файлы.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167701/how-to-activate-share-button-in-android-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто кинув интент:

```
Intent m_musicShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        m_musicShareIntent.setType("audio/*");
        m_musicShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + m_strUriMusic));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(m_musicShareIntent, "Sharing music"));
```